# AsyncHttpClient post request connection refused

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im currently having a problem regarding asynchttpclient post request. i was able to perform a get request using the loopj's asynchttpclient but im stuck with a problem regarding post request.

here is my code for my post request.

```
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

            client.post("http://localhost/lin/mobile_login/", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    String response = new String(responseBody);
                    Log.d("RAW", String.valueOf(responseBody));
                    Log.d("RESPONSE",response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    String err = new String(responseBody);
                    Log.d("ERROR", err);
                    Log.d("EXCE", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            });
```

and it throws

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:157)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

im trying to pass 2 parameter to my post request. hope you can help me regarding my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the question. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with your url `http://localhost/lin/mobile_login/`

Url cannot have the localhost in it. You have to add the IP address here instead of the `localhost` for example `http://192.168.42.37/lin/mobile_login/` whereas `192.168.42.37` will be ip address. You need to find the IP address first. Also make sure server and mobile are on same network.